# Re-trigger rest call if i get read time out error using apex

Tags: apex, rest, callout

How to re-trigger rest call if i get read time out error using apex. Any blog or link would be fine for me or any example also

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop to do this:

```
// Retry 5 times at most. Adjust if necessary.
for(Integer retryCount = 0; retryCount < 5; retryCount++) {
    try {
        HttpResponse res = doCallout();
        processResults(res);
        // We're done, so exit early
        break; 
   } catch(CalloutException e) {
        // We had a problem, so loop back
   }
}
```